# Manipulating a bitmap image in memory with linux

Tags: c++, linux, raspberry-pi

I've done a bit of research but haven't found anything useful so far.

In short I would like to be able to create a bitmap/canvas in memory and use an api which has functions for drawing primitive shapes and text on that bitmap and read the memory directly. This should be completely done in memory and not need a window system or something like Qt or GTK.

Why? I'm writing for the raspberry pi and am interfacing with a 256x64 4 bit greyscale OLED display over spi. This is all working fine so far. I've written a couple of functions for writing text etc, but am wondering if there is already a library I can use. I double buffer the display so I just need to manipulate the image in memory and then read the entire picture in one.

I can easily do this in windows but am not sure the best way to do this in linux

Comment: You know, you might try some of the SVG related libraries. I think most of those can draw to an in-memory buffer. Also libraries designed for producing dynamically generated images for websites would also be a category to look into.

Comment: Not a bad idea, been looking at that. Cairo looks like a good bet, although it doesn't support a palette. I can do a 8 bit alpha based palette but it will require an extra pass before I can display it. Might give it a try and see what speeds I can get.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've used Image Magick to do similar things. It supports Bitmap and SVG. http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php

Comment: I've used that before but AFAIKnew it was only command line, I have just checked though and do have C and C++ libraries called Magick++. It also looks like it might support grey scale images with an arbitrary palette size, cheers, I'll give it a go and see what happens.